# I want to select image using two buttons and want to display those images on two different image view in swift..how could I do this.?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to select image using two buttons and want to display those images on two different image view in swift

```
 func pickimage(){
            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){

                let controller = UIImagePickerController()
                controller.delegate = self
                controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
                controller.allowsEditing = false
                present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

        }
```

Image Picker Delegates

```
extension AdnewDOC : UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


            let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            frontview.image = image
            frontview.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill

         dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)


    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can use `objective-c` associated types `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` like this:** .

I have updated your method, Please pass your image view obejct (which image view you want to show image) from button action method. Like a demo action method for buttons:

```
import ObjectiveC

var myKey = "myObjectKey"


@IBAction func firstButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
            pickimage(imageView: firstImageView)
    }

@IBAction func secondButtonAction(_ sender: Any) {
            pickimage(imageView: secondImageView)
    }


func pickimage(imageView: UIImageView){
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary){
            let controller = UIImagePickerController()
            objc_setAssociatedObject(controller, &myKey, imageView, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            controller.allowsEditing = false
            present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

**And get the image object in delegate method like this:**

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        let imageView = objc_getAssociatedObject(picker, &myKey) as! UIImageView

        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageView.image = image
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> For more understanding how to work `objc_setAssociatedObject` and `objc_getAssociatedObject` please check below links:
>
> > http://blog.corywiles.com/objective-c-runtime-with-swfit
> >
> > http://en.swifter.tips/associated-object/

Comment: not understood .I want to achieve when I tap on button1 the selected image will be applied on imageview1..and when I tap on button2 the selected image will be applied on imageview2.

Comment: I have updated my answer, From button action method you have to call the pickimage method So it will work. You can use this more than buttons action method. In this approach, We are associate the image view with picker controller and when an image gets in delegate method then get the associate object that is image view.